# Scala redundant pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

How could I make this code segment more efficient?

```
v match {
  case y @ A(x) =>
    val x = if (mapping.contains(y))
      mapping.get(y)
    else
      v
    x match {
      case y @ A(i) =>
        lookup(y)
    }
}
```

I feel like the use of two pattern matchers could get reduced to one by declaring a val to retrieve mapping.get(y), but every time I try to do so I get an illegal start of simple expression error:

```
v match {
  case y @ A(x) =>
    val x = if (mapping.contains(y))
      val x = mapping.get(y) //Causes an error
      lookup(x) 
    else
      v
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `mapping` is a `Map`?  If so, use `getOrElse`:

```
val x = mapping.getOrElse(y, v)
```

In your second code block, you need to have braces around the two statements inside the `if`.

But your code doesn't make much sense.  A few reasons:

- You have `case y @ A(x)`, which assigns a value to `x`.  But then, immediately after, you have `x=`, which means that your assigning a brand new `x`, shadowing the old one.
- Similarly, you have `case y @ A(i)`, but you don't use `i`.
- Neither `match` statement has more than one `case`.  This will result in a run time error if the match fails.  But if you know that it won't fail, then the match isn't really useful.

Answer (score 2):

Consider

```
mapping.getOrElse(y,v) match {
  case z @ A(i) => lookup(z)
  case _        => somethingElse
}
```

Comment: Please note @dhg 's instructive comments on enquired code.